# How to verify the dropdown options matching with the UI options in selenium WebDriver using Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have written the code how to read the options from the property file. But I don't know how to verify the same value is there in the UI drop down.

Please anyone help me the same code:

```
@Test()
public void Filterselection_1() throws Exception{

try {
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:/FilterSection/visualization.txt");
      // Get the object of DataInputStream
      DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
      String strLine;
    //Read File Line By Line
      while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
      // Print the content on the console
      System.out.println (strLine);
      }
      //Close the input stream
      in.close();
        }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code given below

1. We Find the drop down element
2. Get all the options to a List
3. Create a List of values from the options list
4. Read the property file line by line
5. Check whether each line is present in the List of values
6. If present, remove that value from the List of Values
7. If not present, print value not present
8. If the List of Values is not empty i.e. it contains values that are not present in the property file, print message stating the same.

   ```
    @Test()
    public void Filterselection_1() throws Exception{
    try {
       //Find the drop down
       Select select  = new Select(DropDownElement);

       //Get all options to a List
       List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions(); 

       //Iterate through the list and create a list of String containing all the values
       List<String> valueList = new ArrayList<String>();
       for (Webelement option : options) {
           valueList.add(option.getText());
       }

       FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:/FilterSection/visualization.txt");
       // Get the object of DataInputStream
       DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
       String strLine;
       //Read File Line By Line
       while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
           //find whether the value is present in the value list
           if (valueList.contains(strLine)) {
               valueList.remove(strLine);
           } else {
              System.out.println(strLine + "not found in the drop down");
           }
       }
       //Close the input stream
       in.close();

       //check if valueList is empty (it will be empty if all the values 
       //in the dropdown are present in the property file)
       if (!valueList.isEmpty()) {
           Ststem.out.println("The following values present in the dropdown are not present in the property file : ");
           for (String s : valueList) {
               System.out.prinyln(s);
           }
       }

   }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
       System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
   }
   ```

   }

Let me know if this helps you.